# Cisco IOS (Wireless) taken channels from the perspective of the accesspoint

Tags: cisco

I can see with "show controllers dot11radio 0" the channel which the cisco accesspoint is currently using.
But is it possible that I can see which channels are taken from other 802.11b/g devices from the from the perspective of the cisco accesspoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a carrier busy test to check the radio activity on bridge channels.

In privileged EXEC mode, enter this command to perform a carrier busy test:

dot11 interface-number carrier busy

Use the show dot11 carrier busy command to re-display the carrier busy test results.

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your reply.